# Is there any tool to convert ms visio flowchart to asciidoc directly?

Tags: open-source, visio, asciidoc

I have a flowchart in visio which I need to embedd inside a asciidoc file .is there any  tool to achieve his?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following workflows for VSD file from Visio:

- Convert VSD to ODG by `vsd2odg` utility and then ODG to PNG by LibreOffice:

  ```
   sudo apt-add-repository vsd2odg
   sudo apt-get install vsd2odg
   vsd2odg file.vsd file.odg

   lodraw --headless --convert-to png file.odg
  ```
- Convert VSD directly to PNG by LibreOffice:

  ```
   lodraw --headless --convert-to png file.vsd
  ```

Then include resulting *file.png* PNG file to the AsciiDoc as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .but instead of converting vsd to png ,is there anyway to convert vsd content to ascii plain text diagrams so that flowchart can be interactive .

Comment: I'm not sure about interactivity. Even [using Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/) ends with static diagrams. But you can try to convert VSD to SVG for better scalability. Or use search for the conversion tool by yourself :)